# Executing multiple Python scripts in a particular order using systemd

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, systemd, boot

I am running Raspbian GNU Linux (9) Stretch, on my Raspberry Pi 3.

### Project Overview

1. Python script which makes use of 2 inputs to the Pi. Calculations are performed based on these inputs, and values are stored in a database.
2. A separate Django website which reads values from this database and updates the content of the web page.

**Django Server** run using: `/home/pi/mysite/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

**Python Script** located at: `/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py`

On startup I would like to first make sure that my Django server is up and running and then start my python script.

### What I have done so far

Initially I started by trying to get the python script to run on startup. To do this I am using a simple `systemd` service as follows.

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This runs without error and initiates the python script on startup.

However, I cannot get my Django server up and running inside the same systemd service since only one `ExecStart` is allowed. I need both to be run in parallel, but the Django up to be started first.

I think I am looking for something like [Wants](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=).

I came across the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195340/systemd-with-multiple-execstart), but I have not managed to implement a working solution. However most of the information is  relevant.

> if Type=simple in your unit file, you can only specify one `ExecStart`, but you can add as many `ExecStartPre`,`ExecStartPost`, but none of this is suited for long running commands, because they are executed serially and everything one start is killed before starting the next one. If `Type=oneshot` you can specify multiple `ExecStart`, they run serially not in parallel.

I tried creating another unit as follows:

```
sudo systemctl edit --force mysite.service


[Unit]
Description=my site

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/mysite/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This works on it's own.

However **I need both to be run in parallel, but the Django up to be started first.**

That's why I edited `myscript.service`as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Scripts/oee_calc.py
Wants=mysite.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The python script is initiated, but the django server is not.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Given that these are two different services, why not just use two different unit files?

Comment: How would I go about executing them at a specific order on startup ?

Comment: You can specify dependencies in systemd units.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @jww, I will keep this in mind for future cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are 2 different systemd unit and define the dependency using `requires`

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py
Requires=dhangioserver.service 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It will also be good to specify `RequiredBy` in DjangoService unit

There is a related spec called `Wants` which differs only in whether service should continue if dependendcy fails or not. Looking at your requirement , it looks like you need `Requires` and not `Wants`

Comment: Ah, thanks I had just edited my question, thinking that I needed something like `Wants`. I will try this and get back. According to the following site I may need to use `Wants` since I would like my python script to run even when there is an issue with Django. https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/

Comment: Ok , if your python script is not dependent on successful start of django service, you need `Wants` and not `Requires`. I would suggest be to give them a useful name service name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in a single unit

```
ExecStart=sh -c "python script1.py & python script2.py"
```