# Rails 5 - How to run multiple systemd services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I have a Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 app that uses ActiveJob to run a background job that sends an email to users upon registration. In development I run `bundle exec rake jobs:work` to start the process. I have my app hosted on DigitalOcean using their Marketplace image which includes a systemd service. This is the systemd service file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/rails.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=appname
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="RAILS_ENV=production"
User=rails
Group=rails
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/appname/current
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma'
TimeoutSec=30s
RestartSec=30s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've read through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195340/systemd-with-multiple-execstart) but I am still not too sure what to do. Should I create multiple services to run the application and the jobs? Or is there a way to get them to run from the same file in parallel (I'm assuming that this type of service needs to be run in parallel)?

Comment: do u use sidekiq ???

Comment: Nope, just using ActiveJob. Would I need to use Sidekiq too? It's quite a small app so I don't wanna make it too complicated. The background job will only be used to the mailers.

Comment: Could I maybe do something like this: ```ExecStartPost=/home/rails/appname/current 'bundle exec rake jobs:work'```? And change the service type to ```forking```?

Comment: do u use one-click rails application droplet in digital ocean???

Comment: Yes, that's the droplet I'm using.

Comment: sidekiq makes this easy ... thats why i chose to use it....

Comment: I'll do some research and see how to do it with Sidekiq

Comment: Will Sidekiq start automatically when Puma is started? Because at the moment my background job works, I just need to have it run automatically. And if I change a job will I need to restart Sidekiq? Or can I just restart the rails service and it will restart too?

Comment: it will automatically restart when ur app deployed

Comment: Awesome, will have a look at it :)

Comment: i wrote a blog how to do it. http://www.enquerer.com/run-sidekiq-in-digital-ocean-production-droplet-for-capistrano-deployed-rails-application/

Comment: Looks like you're still using a systemd service to run Sidekiq. Wouldn't it be better for me to just create another service instead since my background job already works. There will be at most 5-10 registrations per month and concurrent users will be probably under 10 at any given time. It seems like a bit of over kill to install Redis and Sidekiq. I'll definately look into it for larger apps though...